# Turn .txt file into .pdf file on the fly?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pdf, text-files

I'm we're trying to figure out if there would be a way to convert a .txt file to a .pdf file.  Here's the catch.  This needs to be done behind the scenes, and on the fly.  Meaning, with a radio control selected, OnOK would create a .txt file.  Behind the scenes, at run time, we would like for the .txt file to be converted to a .pdf file.  Ideally we would like this to be done by running an executable in the background.  The executable would take input "File.txt" and output "File.pdf".  We're using C++ and Visual Studio 6.

Does anyone have any experience on this?  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a2pdf tool will probably do the trick with minimal effort. Just be sure to turn off perl syntax highlighting.

http://perl.jonallen.info/projects/a2pdf

Answer (score 2):

[libHaru](https://github.com/libharu/libharu) may do what you want.  [Demo](https://github.com/libharu/libharu/blob/master/demo/text_demo.c).

Comment: LibHaru is a good package. Creating a PDF from text will only take a little bookkeeping for line and page endings.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [this](http://www.vulcanware.com/cpp_pdf) open source library. 
Once you have the base for generating PDF documents programmatically, you would still need a method for converting the text to the PDF elements, while keeping the text flow and word wrapping. [This article](http://programmatically) may help. Please pay attention to the `DoText(StreamReader sr)` function. It takes text and purge it into separate lines within the PDF document, keeping the rendered within the margins.

Answer (score 0):

On of the simpler methods that has worked for 3 decades e.g. more than one quarter of a century is place a postscript header before the text then use ghostscript ps2pdf it is the same method as used by some commercial apps such as acrobat

at its most basic

```
Copy heading.ps file.txt printfile.ps
GS -sDEVICE=pdfwrite printfile.ps printfile.pdf
```

Master Example can be seen here

[How to modify this plaintext-to-PDF-converting PostScript from 1992 to actually specify a page size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59959735/how-to-modify-this-plaintext-to-pdf-converting-postscript-from-1992-to-actually)